How to cleanly work around integer promotion
Let's say I have
uint16_t a;
uint16_t b;

and I want to perform ordinary operations on those integers, e.g.
foo(a + b);    // Calling the foo(uint16_t) overload
if (b - a > 10u)
{
    // Do stuff
}

Since the standard only guarantees that int is at least 16-bit wide, depending on the implementation a and b may or may not be smaller than int, which means they may or may not be promoted to int.

If int is 16-bit wide, everything works as expected.
If int is bigger, then foo(int32_t) gets called instead and the compiler emits a Comparison between signed and unsigned warning

Even something like
uint16_t c{a + b};

will conditionally fail to compile, because if int is bigger than 16-bit wide then it becomes a narrowing cast.
What's the proper way to work around this? I want to write standard-compliant code that is guaranteed to reliably do the same thing no matter the implementation
The best I've found is to explicitly cast the result of each operation (without static_cast because that hurts readability too much and makes the compiler complain about redundant casts if int is 16-bit wide):
foo(uint16_t(a + b));
if (uint16_t(b - a) > 10u)
{
    // Do stuff
}

but that is still a bit verbose.
Beyond that, how do I tell my compiler (g++) to forbid (or at least warn about) the use of operands that are not guaranteed to work without integer promotion?

"Standard-compliant code [...] no matter the implementation." -- Then you're bugged, because the exact-width integer types are optional to begin with. If you're on a 32bit DSP without any smaller integer representation, uint16_t will not be defined. ;-) That's why uint_leastN_t exists, which might be larger than N.

The easy way would be to avoid arthimatic for types smaller than int and use int, long long int as your arithmetic types.  On micro controllers that might not work since they have limited resources but on modern x86-64, ARM64 systems using int instead shouldn't be an issue.

Computing uint16(b-a) > 10u is just asking for trouble if you cannot guarantee that a < b. if (b > 10u+a) is cleaner and more likely to do what you intend. But even that can overflow if a is too close to MAXUINT. PS. I haven't seen a serious compiler where int's were only 16 bits wide this millennium (although I expect there are some on PICs and embedded MCUs).

Make a struct my_uint16 { std::uint16_t var; /*operators...*/ }; that doesn't participate in type promotion.  You'll need to implement the operators you care about.

@MartinBrown -- minor correction: the C macro is UINT_MAX, not MAXUINT; the C++ version is std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max().

@NathanOliver In practice I'm receiving data over a bus, with the protocol specification telling me I'm handling 8, 16, etc integers, so those types are the natural representation of what I'm handling. Are you saying that I should never perform operations on them (always converting them to int, etc, beforehand)? Is there any way to make the compiler forbid that?

@MartinBrown If I'm not mistaken, since C++20 converting a negative signed integer into an unsigned integer is no longer implementation-specific behavior and is guaranteed to give a congruent value modulo 2^N, so there should be no issue with uint16_t(b-a). And yes, I work in embedded software, so this is relevant to me as I had to write code a few years ago with 16-bit-wide ints

@DevSolar That... is a good point. I had not realized those types were optional. I'm not quite sure what to make of that. I usually use uint8_t to represent bytes that I receive though communication and have conversion functions to the other fixed-type integers so that I can store them in a way that matches what the documentation says I'm receiving. I don't know what that would look like on a machine like that. I guess the communication primitives would read and write uint32_t and I wouldn't have to worry about those types in the first place

@Eternal you are moving the goal posts. You stated that you wanted a solution for any C compiler no matter the implementation. Now you are relying absolutely on a specific feature that is only present in compilers that implement C++20!

@Eternal Well, the standards leave a lot of leeway like that. However, I somehow doubt a machine where CHAR_BITS != 8 could have a fully compliant C++ compiler. C, yes. C++, not so sure.

@MartinBrown No, I'm not. I said I want to write standard-compliant code that is guaranteed to reliably do the same thing no matter the implementation in a question tagged [c++20], and that means that I want to write something that C++20 guarantees to do what I want and which doesn't rely on knowing more about the size of int than the standard says (i.e. "at least 16 bits")
